# gojs add group template to .model.nodeDataArray

Tags: gojs

We are having issues adding a group template to a page flow document
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-saha-1b46y?file=/index.html

firstly we added the template by creating a `groupTemplateMap`

```
var palette =
            $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",  // create a new Palette in the HTML DIV element
                {
                    // share the template map with the Palette
                    nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,
                    groupTemplateMap: myDiagram.groupTemplateMap,
                    autoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform  // everything always fits in viewport
                });
```

then to get it into the object picker div (on the left) we added it to the

```
 palette.model.nodeDataArray = [
            {}, // default node
            { category: "Source" },
            { category: "grp" }
        ];
```

however the group box does not show up in the picker, rather a duplicate of the `nodeTemplateMap` default element.

according to the documents, `nodeDataArray`

> Gets or sets the array of node data objects that correspond to Nodes, Groups, or non-Link Parts in the Diagram.

how do we add a group to the picker and also to the main div where we can add the standard elements from `nodeTemplateMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set `isGroup` to `true` in the data, not just specify which category of the group template it is. Note that this allows node templates and group templates to have the same names (like the default empty string name)

```
 palette.model.nodeDataArray = [
            {}, // default node
            { category: "Source" },
            { category: "grp", isGroup: true }
        ];
```

Comment: thanks @Simon , I was adding `isGroup: true ` only to the import json, I did not note you needed to also add to the model array as well